# Как сохранить выбранный пункт в select

Tags: php

Ребят, подскажите пожалуйста, у меня такая задача : пользователь ошибочно заполнил форму и отправил ее и нужно чтобы данные которые были введены в поле отображались( это я сделал) и чтобы пункт , который я выбрал в select не выставлялся на начальное значение.

Comment: Понял, спасибо большое за помощь)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Записываем в сессию `$_SESSION['old'] = $_POST['country']` сперва, а потом проверяем уже в самом **html**.

```
<?php session_start() ?> 

<form>  

    <select>   

    <?php foreach ($countries as $country): ?> 
        <option value="<?= $value ?>" <?php if ($_SESSION['old'] == $value) {echo "selected"}?>> 
            <?= $value ?> 
        </option>  
    <?php endforeach ?> 

    </select>

    <input type="submit">  
</form>
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное за помощь, теперь все сразу стало понятно

Comment: @ИванИванов, не за что:))